# Can you use the chi-squared test with tables of real numbers?

Tags: chi-squared-test, matlab, matrix

Consider a $N \times 2$ matrix (MATLAB notation):

```
M = [1.2, 3; 
     1.4, 2; 
     1.8, 1; 
     2.0, 2];
```

That is a $4 \times 2$ matrix where the first column consists of reals and the second of integers.

My question is simply: does it make sense to run a $\chi^2$ test on this and if so how would you go about doing it? I am inclined to say no as tallying frequencies for reals (I have here truncated to a single decimal point, but this could be 5 or 6 decimal points) does not make sense.

Am I way off, on or in between?

Comment: The chi-squared test operates over tables of counts, so no. But what are these data?

Comment: I think that you may use chi-square test, if it is not exact (based on binomial distribution) but is asymptotic, as usual. The Chi-square distribution is continuous and is ok for fractional counts. (I your particular example, though, counts are too low for a chi-square test.)

Comment: In essence a chi-square statistic relies on a sum over ratios. In essence, the numerator is a quadratic form in an approximately normal vector (with mean $\mathbf{0}$ under the null), and the denominator standardizes the numerator (and in many cases this simplifies to a nice simple form). You don't seem to be in a situation where any of those conditions clearly hold.